# How to get rid of all characters after dynamic specified position in a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing

Given a string :

```
address = "Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836, USA"
```

How would you delete all of the string past a specific length past the second comma in order to get rid of the Zip Code and Country? (Output shown below)

```
"Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL"
```

I know you can use a brute form solution such as

```
for(var i = 0; i<address.length;i++){
    if(address[i] == ','){ 
          var number = i+3; 
    }
    //get rid of everything past address[number]
}
```

But that doesnt seem too optimal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) with a limit of 3, then join and then remove the trailing zip code

```js
let addresses = ["Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836, USA", "Tomorrowland 05, Orlando, FL 32836, USA", "Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836, USA, The World"]

addresses.forEach(address => {
  console.log(address.split(',', 3).join(',').replace(/[0-9\-\s]+$/g, ''))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

split the address by space and join the first three elements of the result back together

```js
let address = "Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836, USA"

let result = address.split(' ', 3).join(' ');


console.log(result)
```

Comment: What about `Tomorrow land, Orlando, FL 32836, USA`? assuming there are other cities to test...

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn i'm assuming all the adresses have the same structure ,  yes this is very limited to the string in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the only numbers in the address appear in the ZipCode, you can make use of the RegEx functions in JavaScript such as `string.match(regex)`

```js
let address = "Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836, USA"

truncated_addr = address.match(/^\w[^0-9]+/);
console.log(truncated_addr[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use RegExp `replace()` method:

```
/\s\d.*/g or /\s[0-9]{5}-?[0-9]{0,4}.*/g
```

`/`  begin regex

`\s` a whitespace

`\d{5}` 5 consecutive numbers

`\D` any non-numeric character

`*` zero or more times

`/` end regex

`g` global flag (after the first match, it will continue until end of line)

The second more verbose version is if you may or may not have the lookup code.

`[0-9]{5}` 5 consecutive numbers.

`-?` means zero or one hyphen

`[0-9]{0,4}` zero to 4 consecutive numbers

`\D*` any non-numeric character at any quantity.

`replace()` will find a match and replace it with nothing `''` (2 consecutive quotes).

### Demo

```js
var address0 = "Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836, USA";

var address1 = "Tomorrowland, Orlando, FL 32836-6145, USA";

var str0 = address0.replace(/\s\d{5}\D*/g, '');

var str1 = address1.replace(/\s[0-9]{5}-?[0-9]{0,4}\D*/g, '');

console.log(str0);

console.log(str1);
```

Comment: You mean a street number? The given string doesn't have a street, only city, state, zip and country.

Comment: not necessarily a street, some cities have numbers in their names. This is just something to note of.

Comment: maybe something like this: `/\s\d{5}.*/g` on `Tomorrowland 123rd St., Orlando, FL 32836, USA`

Comment: That's interesting,  [2 places in the entire world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Unusual_place_names#Numeric_names).